# Unable to Deserialize in C# using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, c++, serialization

I'm using protocol buffers to send and receive data between c++ and c# client server application. I'm using protobuf-net for that matter.
I have two proto files, a request command and a response command. I'm able to send and deserialize the command from the c# client to the c++ server. But I'm not able to deserialize in c#. 
I'm getting the byte data in c# though but I get empty response command. 
Consider the code is something like below:

```
    proto.ResponseCommand rsp = new proto.ResponseCommand ();
    using (var data = new MemoryStream ())
    {
    data.write (buffer,0,buffer.length);
    rsp = Serializer.Deserialize<proto.ResponseCommand> (data); 
    }
```

I get the data in bytes in buffer but it doesn't deserialize in the response command.

Comment: Dont know about the implementaiton of protobuf deserialization, but it looks like you never "rewind" the memory stream. Try setting 
data.Position = 0;
other wise it will probably try and read from the *current* position, which will return no data.

Comment: Good point, but I have deserialized previously without changing the position. I think the problem is somewhere in deserializing procedure because everything works good till that command. @neil danson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I was not taking into account the actual size of bytes received, that are returned by the client.Read command. 
After that I also rewind the MemoryStream, thanks to @neil danson